# elements of finite order in G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, infinite-groups

Let G be the quotient group
  (ℤ×ℤ)/⟨2,4⟩

What are the elements of finite order and how do i find how many are there?

Does this make G cyclic?

I am stuck on how to start this

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019589/infinite-group-by-showing-an-element-of-infinite-order).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the the ismorphism $\mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb Z^2$, given by $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\2&1\end{pmatrix} \in SL_2(\mathbb Z)$.

This isomorphism maps $\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\end{pmatrix}$ to $\begin{pmatrix}2\\4\end{pmatrix}$, hence

$$\mathbb Z^2 /\langle (2,4) \rangle \cong \mathbb Z^2/\langle (2,0) \rangle = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z.$$

Should be a gimme to find the elements of finite order.

**Remark.** Speaking in terms of the classifacation of fintely generated abelian groups, one would just say that the Smith normal form of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}2\\4\end{pmatrix}$ is $\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: are the elements then k to 2k?